# How to remove rows that have the same value in two columns and rows that are duplicates of previous observations, regardless of order

Tags: r, subset, unique, pairwise

Consider the data frame `Data` created here:

```r
Data <- data.frame(Location = rep(letters[1:20], each = 10))
```

I want to do pairwise comparisons manually. First, I want to find all possible pairwise combinations between the levels of `Location` in `Data`, so I make the object `Pairs` like this:

```r
Pairs <-expand.grid(unique(Data$Location),unique(Data$Location))
```

Now I want to remove rows from the object `Pairs` where `Pairs$Var1 == Pairs$Var2`, and I want to remove rows that are "duplicates" of previous pairs, but in the opposite order.
In other words, I want to remove rows where `Pairs$Var1 == a` & `Pairs$Var2 == a`, `Pairs$Var1 == b` & `Pairs$Var2 == b`, and so on (i.e., I don't want to compare `Locations` to themselves), and I also don't want the same comparison to be made twice, so if `Var1==a` has already been compared (or already exists earlier in the data.frame) to `Var2 == b`, then I don't want to compare `Var1 == b` to `Var2 == a`, so I need to remove one of these combinations, but not the other (I hope that makes sense).
How can I do this?

We can use `Pairs[Pairs$Var1 == Pairs$Var2,]` to see where `Var1 == Var2`, but this doesn't help with the second problem

Comment: Does `Pairs[Pairs$Var1 < Pairs$Var2,]` do what you want? Depending on your stringsAsFactors setting, you might need `Pairs[as.character(Pairs$Var1) < as.character(Pairs$Var2),]`

Comment: @Bas `Pairs[as.character(Pairs$Var1) < as.character(Pairs$Var2),]` does what I want it to, although I don't quite understand why, would you care to elaborate in a response? That way I can also accept your answer. Also, how can I remove those rows from `Pairs` without making a new object? I have been trying stuff like: `Pairs <- Pairs[-c(as.character(Pairs$Var1) < as.character(Pairs$Var2)),]` but haven't got anything to work

Answer (score 3):

A neat trick to make sure that two columns are different and that there are no symmetrical duplicates is to use the 'greater than' or 'smaller than' operator.

```
Pairs <- Pairs[as.character(Pairs$Var1) < as.character(Pairs$Var2),]
```

or, if you want the inverse,

```
Pairs <- Pairs[as.character(Pairs$Var1) >= as.character(Pairs$Var2),]
```

This works because `a < a` is `False` (an item is not less than itself), and for every pair `(a, b)` either `a < b` or `b < a` is `True`, the other is `False`. That way, for every such pair you only keep one.

Therefore `as.character(Pairs$Var1) < as.character(Pairs$Var2)` returns a vector of `True` and `False` that you can use to slice your `data.frame`. The `as.character()` is needed because one cannot compare `factor`s using `<`.

Answer (score 1):

I post a solution which uses a `for`:

First, remove rows with the same value in both columns:

```
Pairs <- Pairs[Pairs$Var1 != Pairs$Var2,]
```

Second, remove "standard" duplicates:

```
Pairs <- Pairs[!duplicated(Pairs),]
```

Finally, remove duplicates that are in opposite order. My strategy involves creating a temporary columns that allows you (a) not to make the search for cases that you know already are duplicates; (b) make the final filtering. Then, you can remove the temporary column:

```
Pairs$my_duplicated <- FALSE
for(i in 1:nrow(Pairs)){
  if(Pairs$my_duplicated[i] == FALSE){
    my_test <- Pairs$Var2 %in% Pairs$Var1[i] & Pairs$Var1 %in% Pairs$Var2[i]
    Pairs$my_duplicated[my_test] <- TRUE
  }
}
Pairs <- Pairs[!Pairs$my_duplicated,]
Pairs$my_duplicated <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Location = rep(letters[1:20], each = 10))
df <-expand.grid(unique(df$Location),unique(df$Location))
dim(df) # 400 rows x 2 columns
```

Remove the duplicates:

```
df = df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))), ]
dim(df) # 210 rows x 2 columns
```

Remove Var1 = Var2

```
df = subset(df, df$Var1 != df$Var2)
dim(df) # 190 rows x 2 columns
```